# Import-StartLayout - does not correspond to a valid layout file

Tags: xml, windows, powershell, layout, intune

I got an issue with my XML layout file created to pin shortcut to taskbar.
I followed Microsoft documentation to make it but when I tried to manually import with:

`Import-StartLayout -layoutpath "c:\Layout.xml" -Mountpath "C:\"`

I got this error:

`File "c:\layout.xml" does not correspond to a valid layout file`

There is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LayoutModificationTemplate
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification"
    xmlns:defaultlayout="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/FullDefaultLayout"
    xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout"
    xmlns:taskbar="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/TaskbarLayout"
    Version="1">
 <CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection PinListPlacement="Replace">
    <defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
      <taskbar:TaskbarPinList>
        <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\File Explorer.lnk" />
        <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Outlook.lnk" />
        <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Microsoft Edge.lnk"/>
        <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Google Chrome.lnk"/>
        <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Word.lnk"/>
        <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Excel.lnk"/>
        <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Microsoft Teams classic (work or school).lnk"/>
        <taskbar:UWA AppUserModelID="Microsoft.CompanyPortal_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App"/>
        <taskbar:UWA AppUserModelID="MicrosoftCorporationII.QuickAssist_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App"/>
        <taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\myIstraAdista.lnk"/>     
      </taskbar:TaskbarPinList>
    </defaultlayout:TaskbarLayout>
  </CustomTaskbarLayoutCollection>
</LayoutModificationTemplate>
```

Do I miss something?

Comment: EDIT : Works fine now (I edited the XML code) but still got problem when generating my session to perform the modification, the taskbar isnt following my XML file rule. I also tried to put the XML file into the GPO but still failed to apply my layout. Should i tried with a REALLY NEW USER on my computer ? (INFO : I deleted my profil properly from windows)

Comment: Also tried to use the configuration profile in Intune to perform the change to the taskbar. Still not working... Didn't found anything on the internet to correctly perform the modification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used :
`<taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationID="MSEdge"/>`
Instead of the old one :
`<taskbar:DesktopApp DesktopApplicationLinkPath="%APPDATA%\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Microsoft Edge.lnk"/>`

Work perfectly with Intune : Just use `DesktopApplicationID` and `UWA AppUserModelID`